# Hide Facebook app from google search

Tags: facebook, search, hide

Is there any way of hiding our Facebook app from Google search. The app runs in an iFrame and I have tried using a robots.txt file in the same place as the iFrame URL and using meta tags but the app is still shown in google search. I have also submitted a removal request for the iFrame url to google webmaster tools which has not worked.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Which url is indexed by google, the canvas url or the facebook app (apps.facebook.com/YOUR_APP)?

Comment: The apps.facebook.com/ url which im guessing is why my previous attempts didnt work. Im unsure how to hide this URL because it is owned by Facebook.

Comment: I don't think that there's anything you can do about that. It's facebook who gets indexed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove the indexing to something you do not own on Facebook. All applications with a canvas will be indexable. You could remove the indexing for the the contents within the iFrame (i.e. the source URL).